# Loading downloaded image into array and display in uitableview

Tags: ios, image, uitableview

Im trying to add and display downloaded images from a parse query, in my uitableview, but nothign seems to be working. This is how im adding the image to the array:

```
 PFFile *image = (PFFile *)[wallObject objectForKey:@"image"];
 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:image.getData];
 [allImages addObject:img atIndex:0];
```

and this is how im trying to display in my uitableview cell for row at index path method:

```
   NSData *picData = [allImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [(UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:picData]];
```

Im not sure why its not working, any help would be much appreciated!
Please be nice, im new still!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an `UIImage *` object on `allImages` array, then taking a `NSData *` object from it before configuring the cell. Try the following:

```
UIImage *image = [allImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[(UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2] setImage:image];
```

Comment: Great! Also, you can add a property for your `UIImageView` subview and simply set an image like this `cell.myImageView.image = allImages[indexPath.row]`. Remember that there's a built in `UIImageView` property for `UITableViewCell`.